# Microsoft Access - Sum If condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a sum if statement. The statement is supposed to look at a column (Material) to see if it is labeled as Ore or Waste. Then it looks at another column (Tonnage) and sums the value in that column.

Before I tried to add this sum if statement. When I run it now it asks for haulage.tonnage and haulage.material parameters.

The code is as follows:

```
SELECT
            [WeekCounter], 
            [WeekStartDate], 
            [WeekEndDate], 
            [Level], 
            Sum([Ore Round]) AS SumOreRound, 
            Sum([Ore Advancement]) AS SumOreAdvancement,
            Sum( IIF ([Material] = "Ore", [Tonnage], 0)) AS [Ore Tonnes],
            Sum([Waste Round]) AS SumWasteRound, 
            Sum([Waste Advancement]) AS SumWasteAdvancement, 
            Sum( IIF ([Material] = "Waste", [Tonnage], 0)) AS [Waste Tonnes], 
            Sum([Production Round]) AS ProductionRound, 
            Sum([Production Advancement]) AS SumProductionAdvancement

FROM (SELECT 
            Rounds.[Ore Round], 
            Rounds.[Ore Advancement], 
            Week_Numbers.[WeekCounter],
            Rounds.[Waste Round], 
            Rounds.[Waste Advancement], 
            Rounds.[Production Round], 
            Rounds.[Production Advancement], 
            Week_Numbers.WeekStartDate, 
            Week_Numbers.WeekEndDate, 
            Rounds.[Level],
            Haulage.[Tonnage],
            Haulage.[Material]

FROM Rounds INNER JOIN Week_Numbers 
            ON (Rounds.[Date] <= Week_Numbers.WeekEndDate) 
            AND (Rounds.[Date] >= Week_Numbers.WeekStartDate))


GROUP BY 
           [WeekCounter],
           [WeekStartDate],
           [WeekEndDate], 
           [Level];
```

Thank you

Comment: Your sub-select statement uses `Haulage.Tonnage` and `Haulage.Material` but `Haulage` isn't used in the `FROM` clause.  Only `Rounds` and `Week_Numbers` is.

Comment: OK thank you, I wasn't aware that you couldn't do that. I am learning as I go haha. A follow-up question would be how could I put Haulage in the from clause outside of the inner join?

Comment: Generally any tables you select from in your query must be included in the FROM clause.  I can't see why you've got a sub-query though.  At the moment you're join is `Rounds INNER JOIN Week_Numbers ON Conditions`  to add another table you'd use `(Rounds INNER JOIN Week_Numbers ON Conditions) INNER JOIN Haulage ON Conditions`- note the brackets surrounding the first join.

Answer (score 0):

From comments, it appears *Haulage* does not relate to *Rounds* and *Week_Numbers* at all. If so, consider cross joining the table with the `INNER JOIN` by comma-separating *Haulage* with the `INNER JOIN` all under the `FROM` clause.

Do note: cross joins return a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between both sets. Hence, **every** combination of *Haulage* rows will be paired with **every** return of inner join. This can grow very large for large tables (e.g., 1,000 rows of Haulage by 1,000 rows of inner join yields 1,000,000 rows).

```
SELECT w.[WeekCounter], 
       w.[WeekStartDate], 
       w.[WeekEndDate], 
       r.[Level], 
       Sum(r.[Ore Round]) AS SumOreRound, 
       Sum(r.[Ore Advancement]) AS SumOreAdvancement,
       Sum(IIF(h.[Material] = 'Ore', h.[Tonnage], 0)) AS [Ore Tonnes],
       Sum(r.[Waste Round]) AS SumWasteRound, 
       Sum(r.[Waste Advancement]) AS SumWasteAdvancement, 
       Sum(IIF(h.[Material] = 'Waste', h.[Tonnage], 0)) AS [Waste Tonnes], 
       Sum(r.[Production Round]) AS ProductionRound, 
       Sum(r.[Production Advancement]) AS SumProductionAdvancement

FROM Haulage h, 
     Rounds r INNER JOIN Week_Numbers w
                ON (r.[Date] <= w.WeekEndDate) 
               AND (r.[Date] >= w.WeekStartDate))
GROUP BY 
       w.[WeekCounter],
       w.[WeekStartDate],
       w.[WeekEndDate], 
       r.[Level];
```

Comment: Thanks for the input it is very helpful. A follow up question would be how can I avoid the cartesian production? When I try the code I get some numbers back that are way too large and I am suspect that it is because they are taking the product, not the sum.

Comment: Again, does *Haulage* in any way relate to *Rounds* and/or *Week_Numbers*? Relational databases are hinged on relational tables, so tables should not be treated like spreadsheets as just dump repositories. Please advise on your schema. You may need to restructure for relationships.

Comment: The only relationship that Haulage, Rounds, and Week_Numbers is by date. Each table record is dated and that is how I am trying to relate each table.

Comment: Can you post some example data of all three tables (just a few rows of pertinent columns)? There may be a way to join. You can even add a `WHERE` clause in this solution for interval filter on date field in *Haulage* like you do for *Rounds*.